# Time derivative of an invariant probability measure

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, vector-fields

Consider a dynamical system defined through  a vector field $F$ in $M \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ that generates a flow $\Phi^t$ of the form
$$\bf{\Phi^t X_0 = X}  \ , $$ 
being $X_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the initial condition.

Let's say that an invariant probability measure $\mu$ is defined in $M$. So it satisfies:
$$\mu(B) = \mu(\mathbf{\Phi^{-t}}(B)) ,$$
being $B$ any set in the $\sigma$-algebra of $M$. Considering that $\mu$ is a probability measure it should satisfy the principle of conservation of probability, which  I am going to write as
$$\mu(B) = \mu(\mathbf{\Phi^{-t}}(B)) = c, $$
with $0  < c \leq 1$.
My question is, can we rewrite this last equation using a total derivative with respect to $t$? I am thinking in something as
$$\frac{d}{dt}\mu = 0 \ ?$$ 
Is this correct? I am not an expert with measures, so any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Liouville equations.
See here, for example
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28Hamiltonian%29

Basically if you want to understand what evolution $\phi(X,t)$ of a certain function $\phi_0 = \phi(X,0)$  under the action of the system you take its derivative with respect to the system i.e. $ d \phi(\Phi^t X_0,t) / dt $. If you know equations of the flow you can write it explicitly using chain rule. Then you can write an equation (you solve for $\phi$ such that $ d \phi(\Phi^t X_0,t) / dt  = 0$)  which corresponds to what you want if you then consider measure $\phi d Leb$, where $Leb$ is Lebesgue measure.

Of course it works well for measures that have densities wrt Lebesgue measure, otherwise you may have to use weak formulations.

Comment: thank you. In fact, I was thinking in Liouville's equation; your explanation makes completely sense for me.